# Cannot login in to arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, login

I installed arch a day ago and it was fine until yesterday but after I changed some settings in the `/etc/pam.d/system-local-login` to use fingerprint login and reboot, I can't login in to arch linux. So I used my bootable usb to get into arch and changed the root password and tried deleting the user and making it again but nothing seems to work. Also I can now login in the bootable usb but cannot login with the same password when I boot normally.

Also, the `/etc/pam.d/system-local-login` doesn't seem to be changed even though I thought I changed it. What should I do?

I am using gnome

Comment: Just to make sure that you are doing this right. Have you tried the methods provided in [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reset_lost_root_password) when it comes to resetting the root password? You are using [fprint](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fprint) for this, am I right? Have you tried your new password in TTY?

Comment: Yes I tried like the wiki but it didn't work :(

Comment: @HyeonseokJung, did you do the *MOUNT* before you tried to change the password ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply well yes I did mount the partition to /mnt and did the changes inside arch-chroot. I tried to solve the problem but I just reinstalled arch after all